How to access hostvars in `compose` section in dynamic inventory file
I've put together this inventory_aws_ec2 file:
---
plugin: aws_ec2
filters:
  tag:Name:
    - "do-compose-*"
groups:
  bastion: "'mgmt-bastion' in tags.get('Name', '')"
  apps: "'apps' in tags.get('Name', '')"
hostnames:
  - tag:Name
compose:
  ansible_user: '"ubuntu"'
  ansible_host: public_ip_address if "mgmt-bastion" in tags.get('Name', '') else private_ip_address
  ansible_ssh_common_args: >-
    "" 
    if "mgmt-bastion" in tags.get('Name', '') 
    else "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p ubuntu@{{ hostvars[groups['bastion'][0]].public_ip_address }}'"

I have problem with the last variable ansible_ssh_common_args, b/c I need to reference public_ip_address of the bastion server when trying to access apps hosts.
I can't seem to figure out how to access hostvars[groups['bastion'][0]].public_ip_address part. Hostvars is available in playbooks, but seems to be not availabe in compose section. Is there any other way to get that information?
Besides that, I also tried accessing hostvars in groups_vars and common_vars like this, no luck:
---
bastion_ip_address: hostvars['do-compose-mgmt-bastion'].public_ip_address

It seems that hostvars is only available in playbooks. Could anyone confirm that?

Have you tried else "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'ProxyCommand ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p ubuntu@" ~ hostvars[groups['bastion'][0]].public_ip_address ~ "'"?

@β.εηοιτ.βε I did just now, but it seems that hostvars is simply only available in playbooks.
